# How can I make user won't receive (APNC)notifications when they quit the app?

Tags: swift, notifications, swiftui

I want user won't receive notifications when they quit the app

What I have tried is to detect when the user quit the app, and if the user quit the app executing this code: `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()`

So I tried to detect whether using quitting app by this func: `optional func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)` But I'm not sure where and how to call it when the user quit the app and at the same time execute this code:`UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()`

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: How about calling `application.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()`?

Comment: @Cerlin Thank you for the response. ;) Yeah, that's definitely a good idea, how can I call that function when the moment user quit the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    application.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

If you want the app to stop all the notifications as soon as the app has gone into the background, you can use

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    application.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

NOTE: If you use the second option, don't forget to re-register for push notifications when the app enters foreground again

Comment: Thank u so much for the help ;).  So I tried adding that func to Contentview.Swift, but it doesn't work.. Maybe the way I add that func was wrong..  Should I add that func at different place?

Comment: Yes. Add that in `AppDelegate.swift`

Comment: Thank for the response again :), so I tried adding that func at ' AppDelegate.swift'  But the app keeps sending notifications no matter I quit the app. Is there anything else I should do more after adding that func?

Comment: Which system are you using to send push notifications? FCM or APNS?

Comment: I'm using APNC sir !

Comment: I am not sure what APNC is. Apples push notification service is called APNS

Answer (score 1):

This code example to remove all pending notification.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
}
```

This code example for unregistering remote notifications.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Comment: This will only remove the pending notifications in the notification page. This doesnt unregister the push notification